# Microsoft Access - Creating a form which looks up data between 2 dates

Tags: forms, ms-access

For my College assignment, I have to create a database in Access, I have done 99% of my database, apart from this section which I'm stuck on.

In my DB, I have a tickets table, which contains records on order information and a field containing a date. For my assignment, I have to create a Form which reads from a Query.

For example, in my Form i have already created i have 2 Combo boxes with the dates already pulled from the Query. I need to be able to drop down one of the boxes and input 1 date, and then drop down the other box and select a different date, press a button and it generate me a Report.

The part I am asking for help on is the expression which is used to look up the data inside the Query. I tried using this expression, which Access said was too complicated.

```
[Forms]![frmOrdersBetweenTwoDates]![Combo33] And [Forms]![frmOrdersBetweenTwoDates]![Combo36]
```

My full SQL query is:

```
SELECT tblTickets.CustomerID, tblCustomers.FullName, tblCustomers.AddressLine1, tblTickets.OrderNumber, tblTickets.OrderDate
FROM tblCustomers INNER JOIN tblTickets ON tblCustomers.[CustomerID] = tblTickets.[CustomerID]
WHERE ((("WHERE [OrderDate]") Between [Forms]![frmOrdersBetweenTwoDates]![Combo52] And [Forms]![frmOrdersBetweenTwoDates]![Combo54]));
```

My expression/query now returns the report, but there is no data inside the report. How could i fix this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Should post the complete query statement. Expect the filter clause should be like:

`WHERE [date fieldname] BETWEEN [Forms]![frmOrdersBetweenTwoDates]![Combo33] AND [Forms]![frmOrdersBetweenTwoDates]![Combo36]`

However, I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer to use the WHERE argument of OpenReport (same for OpenForm), in VBA:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "report name", , , "[date fieldname] BETWEEN #" & Me.Combo33 & "# AND #" & Me.Combo36 & "#"`

Comment: thanks for your reply, Im using your top expression, and when i input my dates, nothing is returned in the report, why is this? The dates im inputting are correct.

Comment: You should still show the full SQL statement. Edit your question. Is the query referenced in the report RecordSource property? Another alternative is to put the filter criteria directly in the report Filter property instead of query. The VBA code shown essentially does that.

Comment: I updated the OP, my tutor doesn't want us to touch VBA, which is stupid, we have to complete the task via expressions.

Comment: Why are the combobox names different? Interesting, the VBA is using an expression - the same one. Macros are also off-limits? I expect the lesson focus is dynamic parameterized query. Ok, options are to put criteria in query or in Filter property. Remove the quote marks from the query.